# Limit Impact of Broken Markup

Tags: html, css

We have a website that displays employee-generated html in a div located in the middle of the page. Unfortunately, up to this point, no validation has been done on the html that was being entered, so there are unclosed tags that "bleed" into the subsequent code. For example, if the employee forgot to close a `<strong>` tag, the rest of the page ends up bold.

We are working on fixing up the invalid html, but in the meantime, is there any way to limit the scope of what they've entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple but working solution would be to put this markup inside an <iframe>. Remember that this solution limits the use of JavaScript in the code inside the <iframe> though.

Comment: I think your answer got scrambled. The important part isn't showing up for me.